# Renaming a single file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename an audio file but I keep getting `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

In my program, each user has a directory that holds the users files. I obtain the path for each user by doing the following:

```
current_user_path = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], user.username)

/Users/johnsmith/Documents/pythonprojects/project/files/john
```

Now I want to obtain the path for the existing file I want to rename:

```
current_file_path = os.path.join(current_user_path,form.currentTitle.data)

/Users/johnsmith/Documents/pythonprojects/project/files/john/File1
```

The path for the rename file will be:

```
new_file_path = os.path.join(current_user_path, form.newTitle.data)

/Users/johnsmith/Documents/pythonprojects/project/files/john/One
```

Now I'm just running the rename command:

```
os.rename(current_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Comment: Did you make sure the file exists? What is the output if you do `os.listdir(current_user_path)`?

Comment: is it at all possible that the file has an extension? your filename seems to just be `File1` without an extension but files very frequently have extensions.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you're right.  All i had to do was `current_file_path +='.m4a'`  and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

you can use [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) for rename single file.

to avoid

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

check if file exist or not.

here is the working example:

```
import os

src = "D:/test/Untitled003.wav"
dst = "D:/test/Audio001.wav"

if os.path.isfile(src):
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the OS says there's no such file or directory, that's the gospel truth.  You're making a lot of assumptions about where the file is, constructing a path to it, and renaming it.  It's a safe bet there's no such file as the one named by `current_file_path`, or no directory to `new_file_path`.

Try `os.stat(current_file_path)`, and similarly double-check the new file path with `os.stat(os.posixpath.dirname(new_file_path))`.  Once you've got them right, `os.rename` will work if you've got permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the current working directory to the one you want to work with. This code below should give you a simple walk through of how you should  go about it:

```
import os
print (os.getcwd())
os.chdir(r"D:\Python\Example")
print (os.getcwd())
print ("start")
def rename_files():
    file_list= os.listdir(r"D:\Python\Example")
    print(file_list)
    for file_name in file_list:
            os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"0123456789")) rename_files()
print("stop")
print (os.getcwd())
```